# CakePHP redirect with status code 404

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, http-status-code-404, cakephp-2.0

For CakePHP errors I know that there exists CakeError and AppError solutions.
But I need to make a redirection within controller.

In **AppController** there exists:

```
function afterFilter() {
    if ($this->response->statusCode() == '404')
    {
        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'mycontroller',
            'action' => 'error', 404),404
        );
    }
}
```

But this doesn't create a 404 status code. It creates a 302 code.
I changed code to this:

```
$this->redirect('/mycontroller/error/404', 404);
```

But the result is same.

I added this, it didn't work also deprecated:

```
$this->header('http/1.0 404 not found');
```

How can I send a 404 code within controller redirect ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to return a 404 error, use the built in CakeError support for it:

```
throw new NotFoundException();
```

You can throw this exception from your controller and it should generate a 404 response.

There are more built-in exceptions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html).

If you are interested in making a custom error page, then see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620363/cakephp-2-0-how-to-make-custom-error-pages?rq=1).

Otherwise, I don't think it is possible to return a 404 header code and still redirect. Http specifies redirect status codes to [be in the 300s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), and this is the convention CakePHP follows.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason using redirect() will change the status code to 3xx. If you want to execute another action and still return 404, you can do as follows:

```
$this->controller->response->statusCode(404);
$this->controller->render('/mycontroller/error/404');
$this->controller->response->send();
```

This will execute Mycontroller::error(404) without redirect.

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP 3](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Network.Exception.NotFoundException.html)

```
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
...
throw new NotFoundException(__('Article not found'));
```