# Cakephp Custom Error pages

Tags: cakephp

I am referring to the problem that has already been asked. [CakePHP 2.0 - How to make custom error pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620363/cakephp-2-0-how-to-make-custom-error-pages)

It gives me a lot idea of solving out the problem but instead of thowing exception I want to use it for all of my controller and actions. It suggested me to do where ever at particular location I want `throw new NotFoundException();` I want it everywhere I mean where so ever controller or action is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With debug turned off all your error are converted to either 400 or 500 errors. So you just need to customize your `app/View/Errors/error400.ctp` and `app/View/Errors/error500.ctp` as required.

Comment: But customissing these two files remains the Cakephp header and red bar always their. I can't remove these two element.

Comment: So make a new layout file and set `$this->layout` to that in the error views.

Comment: this wuld be my next question. I have created layout  in my layout folder not where to set `$this->layout`. Is it would be set in view file that are in `app/View/Errors/error400.ctp` or `app/View/Errors/error500.ctp`