# Cakephp error custom page

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello I am new in cakephp and I want to show an error page if someone enter wrong url in my cakephp application.

I am using this code as per given example on internet

[CakePHP 2.0 - How to make custom error pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620363/cakephp-2-0-how-to-make-custom-error-pages)

I am unable to see any custom error page in my application.I have used all the given steps added in that url

Comment: I am not getting anything as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the second answer:

> To customize the content of a 404-error page and don't need custom
>   logic, simply edit the contents of app/View/Errors/error400.ctp.

Note that you need to also set your debug level to zero to see your custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is handle all errors in AppController.php

`public function beforeRender() {
        parent::beforeRender();
        if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
            $this->redirect(array(
               'controller' => 'ExampleController', 'error_action'));
        }
}`

And make view View/ExampleController/error_action.ctp with your needs.