# How can we handle custom errors in cakePHP?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

How can we handle custom errors in cakePHP?, 
For instance, if end user modify URL directly,

eg: http://localhost/cake/topics/view/6

in case if this value not available, how can we handle this type of situation.
Code

```html
if (!$this->Topic->exists($id)) 
  {
   //$this->cakeError('fatal_error');
   //$this->fatal_error('Invalid topic');
   //throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
    throw new NotFoundException(('Could not find that post'));
  }
  
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Topic.' . $this->Topic->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('topic', $this->Topic->find('first', $options));
```

just write

```html
throw new NotFoundException(('Could not find that post'));
```

it is not good it seems.
so how can we handle  it ?

please help  me

Comment: redirect to a 404 page don't throw a error that the user has no idea of what it does is bad for ux

Answer (score 0):

A better way to just redirect it to 404 page .

You can do it with answers of questioned at: [CakePHP 2.0 - How to make custom error pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620363/cakephp-2-0-how-to-make-custom-error-pages)