# Does not have a custom 404 Error Page

Tags: html, cakephp

I have setup 404 pages using cakephp controllers, and it is working fine when I try to go to a page that does not exist it comes back with http response 404 and the 404 page is displayed, but tools like woorank.com and PowerSeo always said that a custom 404 page is not defined?

Is there any thing I can do in the .htaccess file to make those tools know that I have 404 page defined? I have added the ErrorDocument 404 /404.html to .htaccess but still same error. Where do they look for the 404 page defined?

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
       RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
       RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com [L,R=301]
      </IfModule>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 10 years"
Header unset Pragma
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 3):

From [CakePHP Book:](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions)

> By convention CakePHP will use **App\Controller\ErrorController** if it exists. Implementing this class can give you a configuration free way of customizing error page output.

[Here is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379239/1127933) how to create ErrorController

next add in your router:

**CakePHP 2.x:**

```
Router::parseExtensions('html');
Router::connect(
    '/404.html',
    array('controller' => 'errors', 'action' => 'error404'),
);
```

**CakePHP 3.x:**

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['html']);
    $routes->connect(
        '/404.html',
        ['controller' => 'Errors', 'action' => 'error404'],
    );
});
```